# Python dictionary : update thru input

Tags: python, dictionary, input, python-3.8

Here "anotherName" is a dictionary in a module and I want to update it according to user input. How is that done? The line saying "anotherName[input]" does not work since input is a built in function but I don+t see what should be done about it, to reference to input in another way. "ans" raises the same error.

```
def newPlace():
    ans = fieldinR62.get()
    for x in anotherName.items():
        if ans in anotherName:
            print("This place is already stored")
            break
         if ans not in anotherName:          
            ans = input                                                    
            anotherName[input]
            top = Toplevel()
            top.title("first highly desireable window")
            top.geometry("400x200+120+120")
            button1 = Button(top, text="Add feature", command=open_window).grid(row=1, column=4, sticky=W, pady=10)
            fieldinEMAIL = tk.Entry (top, ).grid(row = 2, column = 5, sticky=W, pady=20)
```

This is another solution I found out works, but now I need to make it work inside a function.

```
d = {"username": "XYZ", "email": "xyz@gmail.com", "location": "Mumbai"}



r=str(input())
d[r] =' '

print(r)
print(d)
```

Comment: Normally, you wouldn't use both `input` and `tk` in the same app; `input` is for terminal (command-line) apps, while `tk` is for GUI apps. Can you clarify your question to eliminate one or the other?

Answer (score 0):

The function `input` must be called with parenthesis. Also, a dictionary consists of key-value pairs and a new pair is added to the dictionary like this: `dict[key] = value`.

You must replace this 2 lines:

```py
ans = input                                                    
anotherName[input]
```

With these:

```py
ans = input()
anotherName[key] = ans
```

Where key is some unique value for every new input. Probably some kind of userId, but you must determine that for yourself. As long as the key is unique and thus not already in the dictionary. You can check if a key already exists in a dictionary with a simple if-statement:

```py
if key in dict:
    # key is already in dict, try new key or throw error.
else:
    # key is not already in dict and is safe to use.
```

Comment: This does not work. I want to add a new previously non existent key.

Comment: I see the Shell giving the response "dictionary changed size during iteration" but when I look through the dictionary (that is in a module) it is not there/visible. Do I have to "save it from the memory"?

Comment: I do this with : anotherName.update({'---newkey---': 'Idontwantanyvauejustyetisitreallyrequired'})

Comment: I get the same result with this:   anotherName['nytt'] = 'fgfgfgfgfg'.

Comment: I moved the dictionary to tha same script as the rest but no updating, no difference. Even tho I get no error message.

Comment: This is another solution I found out works, but now I need to make it work inside a function.


d = {"username": "XYZ", "email": "xyz@gmail.com", "location":"Mumbai"}


input = input
r=str(input())
d[r] =' '

print(r)
print(d)

Comment: Why are you iterating over the dictionary with `for x in anotherName.items()` anyway? You probably don't need to do that?